# Is it easy to update ubuntu beta to ubuntu final release?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

At this moment I am preparing a virtual server to host a web application which needs php5.3

The virtual server base image is always Hardy (8.04 LTS). There is no php5.3 until the upcoming release in a few days: Lucid (9.04 LTS).

I am seeing to options:
 - waiting until the final version is released and then start preparing this server
 - Now upgrading to the beta (do-release-upgrade --devel-release) and when the final release has come upgrading to that

For time constraints I would prefer the second option. I only can't find whether it will be easy to upgrade from a beta to the 'clean' final release. Is this possible in an easy way. Will it have any drawback for security or will there be any traces left of it being ever a beta release?

Note: the server will not go into production before the LTS is really installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucid it's 10.04 LTS ;) (that is april 2010 so i'd just wait a couple of days).
btw it should be no problem upgrading from beta to stable release...
Actually could be less hassle than upgrading directly from 8.04.